# How to generate sql without a database connection using jooq

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I am playing with some jooq code. I noticed to create sql using jooq it forces you to create a database connection. Wanted to know how to do this without a database connection:

```
String url = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
String user = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username");
String pass = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass)) {
    DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.SQLSERVER2014);
    String sql = create.select().from(DATA1).offset(100).limit(20).getSQL();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No idea what you're doing but you could fire up [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) database embedded within your jvm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't pass any connection to the `using()` call:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.SQLSERVER2014);
String sql = create.select().from(DATA1).offset(100).limit(20).getSQL();
```